# Haskell network package documentation

Tags: networking, haskell

I want to experiment with network programming in Haskell. The problem I have is that the documentation for the `network` package is pretty scarce, especially the one for [Network.Socket](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.2.1.7/doc/html/Network-Socket.html) which I want to use.

Do you know of some other references or clearly written projects where I can see how to use it? Are there any good alternatives to `network`?

Comment: From a quick glance, `Network.Socket` appears to be little more than a wrapper around the [standard Berkeley sockets API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), so I imagine the documentation for it is scarce because there's already plenty of [material for using the same API](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) out there.

Answer (score 3):

Network.Socket is just bindings to the Berkeley socket API.  You should read [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) to network programming.

EDIT: If you're on *nix then see the man pages for socket, bind, listen, accept, connect, recv, send and family.  No matter your OS, there are also some higher level packages on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org) (ex: [network-fancy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-fancy), [network-server](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-server)) you should look at if all you want to do is communicate (and not get involved in the gritty details).

Answer (score 0):

[Chapter 27 of ``Real World Haskell''](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/sockets-and-syslog.html) introduces networking in Haskell.